# Project & BAU Pipeline/Portfolio tools

Tags: tools

We have a team with around 4 to 5 concurrent major projects, 10 minor projects and about the same number of BAU projects.

Are there any tools that you use to manage and visualise your departments work and pipeline in similar situations?

I'm looking for a visual representation of resource allocation over time. Really like a product roadmap but for multiple products. At the moment I'm using a combination of MS Project & excel but wondering if there's anything else out there.

Answer (score 1):

Our product, TrackerSuite.Net, has a [Project Resource vs. Available bar chart graph](http://www.trackersuite.net/scrn_project_resource_widget.html).  For more details about resource workloads, it also offers [resource availability grids](http://www.trackersuite.net/scrn_resource_availability.html) that can be filtered by department, manager, project status, priority and more.  You can also drill down on individual resource assignments. If you'd like a hands-on evaluation, you can register for immediate access to a demonstration site.

**DISCLAIMER: I am affiliated with this product.**

Answer (score 0):

We make a tool specifically targeted towards product development called OneDesk

It allows an overview of all projects in roadmap views, as well as being able to track and visualise resource allocation over time.

[See the roadmapping functionality here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEo58_q4EN8&feature=plcp), and sign up for a free trial to [create product roadmaps](http://www.onedesk.com/lp/product-roadmapping-software/).

NOTE: As per the guidelines in the FAQ, I disclose that I'm the Community Manager of this product.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this before but did spend some time looking into some of the [Service Now](http://www.servicenow.com/project-portfolio.do) product suite. They offer a SaaS model and local installations, and the best part is that product suite is extensive and well integrated.